# Is it possible to melt soft metals with household current?

Tags: current-source, arc

I'm an electronics enthusiast with an interest in welding. Just out of curiosity, I was playing around with the voltage in my house (using proper safety techniques) and I started wondering if the arc from the AC in a standard wall socket could melt some metals, like lead or copper, if non-combustible electrodes were used to strike the arc.

Comment: Yes you could. You can  also weld with a 12V car battery if you wanted  but directly using mains to weld is liable to win you a Darwin. Personally I'd stick to a ready made (and fully tested) welding machine.

Comment: For lead, a high power soldering iron or a stove will do, You don't want lead fumes and you *really* don't want lead in an arc...

Comment: Darwin Awards are Mother Nature's way of gene pool reduction

Comment: ...usually gathered from the shallow end of the pool.

Comment: There was a Scientific American article (Amateur Scientist section I believe) that gave instructions for screwing around with house current ("Build your own arc welder!"). The only thing I remember was that whatever they did had a 1500 watt heating element in series with the rest of the equipment, reasoning that in case of a dead short the worst that would happen is that the heating element would, well, heat. This won't keep it from killing you (or setting the house on fire) but -will- keep the breaker from popping.

Comment: *"Is it possible to melt soft metals with household current?"* - If it's not, I'm going to demand a refund for all my fuses.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how fast you want to melt soft metals.

Put a screwdriver under a power cable staple behind the wall near the breaker panel and you can even vaporize copper wire and steel in screwdriver  in milliseconds (bang) and spray it all over your plastic safety lens, as I have done in my learning phase 40 yrs ago.(newbie days in Rec Room construction)

To do it in a controlled fashion only needs some thermodynamic heat equations and sufficient thermal resistance in an insulted ceramic oven and sufficient heat.

Mass Spectrometers can convert the sample into a plasma with RF energy vacuum, helium/argon burn it and accelerate it past a grid then deflect it and measure the mass of each plasma particle deflected.

A 300W RF coil ( that looks like 1/8" copper plumbing) can make an iron rod red hot in seconds, but not melt it.

A 1000:1 turns ratio spot welder melts metal and welds it instantly by stepping up the AC current in large jaws ( 1 turn output loop) with 10kA at the tungsten electrodes.(preferred)

TIG/MIG/Plasma Welding uses a similar approach with a low current trigger voltage to bridge the gap and then the high current low voltage provides the follow-on energy with I²R [watt] * Rth [degC/W]/time[s] for thermal resistance Rth to get degC/second rise to melting point. where Arc current is inverse to R such that R=k1/I and fuse time = k2 * Amp-seconds [As]

Comment: So, ignoring the problem of breaker, if I hooked the socket power up to some graphite electrodes and switched it on in some kind of crucible set up, the arc could hypothetically melt metal that I put inside

Comment: Also on the spoy welder detail: that might work, I have some solid copper wire lying around

Comment: Nope sorry that wont' work on metals. Carbon has a lower melting point but is used for gas fusion search lamps.

Comment: Any ideas for electrode materials then.?

Comment: Only Tungsten is affordable.  There are better with more $

Comment: So just some tungsten rods then?

Comment: that's what I indicated in my answer Tungsten. Obviously size matters for current density. Rod, wire depends on kA and temp

Comment: Okay, thanks. I have a setup that I will try later, once I have some goggles for the arc

Comment: Be aware that high currents also produce a high force and will tend to move loose rods to stick to surface and short out the arc.

Comment: My experiment involves clamps that I can adjust the electrodes with in an anti-virus environmemt